# Problema de serviço de autorização

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-identity, jwt

Eu estou fazendo um curso de aspnet core e em determinado trecho, é realizada a configuração da parte de autorização, porém o professor do curso foi testar um endpoint post de categoria e o mesmo foi bloqueado 401 unauthorized, normal até ai tudo bem, mas era pra ter dado a mesma coisa no meu endpoint , mas no meu dá 201 created e cria a categoria normal, sendo que está basicamente a mesma coisa do que o do professor fez em seus videos, pelo menos eu acho heheh, até agora não vi diferença.

vou mostrar alguns trechos para que alguem me ajude

arquivo de configuração com as configurações do token

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Connection": "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=IWantDb;Trusted_Connection=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;Integrated Security=True"
  },
  "jwtBearerTokenSettings": {
    "SecretKey": "erg#$Af@$A#F$#reggg5ew4g4t4t",
    "Issuer": "IWantAppIssuer",
    "Audience": "Audience",
    "ExpiryTimeSeconds": 60
  }
}
```

esse é o meu program

```
using System.Text;
using IWantApp.Endpoints.Categories;
using IWantApp.Endpoints.Employees;
using IWantApp.Endpoints.Security;
using IWantApp.Infra.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(e => e.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connection")));

builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    // aqui se pode personalizar a convensão das senhas
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(e =>
{
    e.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    e.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateActor = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["jwtBearerTokenSettings:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["jwtBearerTokenSettings:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["jwtBearerTokenSettings:SecretKey"]))
    };
});

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddScoped<QueryAllUsersWithClaimName>();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
 
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapMethods(CategoryGetAll.Pattern, CategoryGetAll.HttpMethods, CategoryGetAll.Handler);
app.MapMethods(CategoryPost.Pattern, CategoryPost.HttpMethods, CategoryPost.Handler);
app.MapMethods(CategoryPut.Pattern, CategoryPut.HttpMethods, CategoryPut.Handler);
app.MapMethods(CategoryDelete.Pattern, CategoryDelete.HttpMethods, CategoryDelete.Handler);

app.MapMethods(EmployeesPost.Pattern, EmployeesPost.HttpMethods, EmployeesPost.Handler);
app.MapMethods(EmployeesGetAll.Pattern, EmployeesGetAll.HttpMethods, EmployeesGetAll.Handler);

app.MapMethods(TokenPost.Pattern, TokenPost.HttpMethods, TokenPost.Handler);

app.Run();
```

meu gerador de token

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using IWantApp.Models.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace IWantApp.Endpoints.Security
{
    public class TokenPost
    {
        public static string Pattern => "/token";
        public static string[] HttpMethods => new string[] { HttpMethod.Post.ToString() };
        public static Delegate Handler => Action;

        public static IResult Action(LoginRequest loginRequest, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var user = userManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginRequest.Email).Result;

            if (user is null) return Results.NotFound("User not found!");
            if (!userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, loginRequest.Password).Result) return Results.BadRequest("Bad password!");

            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(configuration["jwtBearerTokenSettings:SecretKey"]);
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                    new (ClaimTypes.Email, loginRequest.Email)
                }),

                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature),

                Issuer = configuration["jwtBearerTokenSettings:Issuer"],

                Audience = configuration["jwtBearerTokenSettings:Audience"]
            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            return Results.Ok(new { token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token) });
        }

    }
}
```

e o endpoint de categoria que era pra ter sido bloqueado mas não é ;-;

```
using IWantApp.Infra.Data;
using IWantApp.Models.DTOs;
using IWantApp.Models.Products;
using IWantApp.Utilities;

namespace IWantApp.Endpoints.Categories
{
    public class CategoryPost
    {
        public static string Pattern => "/categories";
        public static string[] HttpMethods = new string[] { HttpMethod.Post.ToString() };
        public static Delegate Handler => Action;

        public static IResult Action(CategoryDTO categoryDTO, ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            var category = new Category(categoryDTO.Name, "nome teste", "nome teste");

            if (!category.IsValid)
            {
                return Results.ValidationProblem(category.Notifications.ConvertToProblemDetails());
            }

            context.Categories.Add(category);
            context.SaveChanges();

            return Results.Created("/categories", category.Id);
        }

    }
}
```

espero a resolução do problema: no caso, preciso que o endpoint de categoria seja bloqueado

Answer (score 0):

Faltou o código da Controller da API.

Mas o que precisa é colocar lá a TAG `[Authorize]` assim ela irá exigir a autenticação.